# Gapless audio loop HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am creating a button that when clicked should play a song on repeat. When it starts the song again there seems to be a small delay. The song is 10.54 seconds long in a .wav file. Because the clip is so short when it repeats you really notice it. How can I remove the gap?

```js
function toggleBox(audioId, element) {
  var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);

  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio5" preload="auto" loop>
    <source src="sonidos/sonido5.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

<div class="box" onclick="toggleBox('audio5', this)"></div>
```

I have tried answers from other people but none work.

Comment: Are you sure there's no dead space at the start or end of the wav file? Has it been trimmed accurately?

Comment: Adding `loop` should have fixed it, the alternative is loading it in a buffer and playing that continuously (I remember having to do that when implementting sound FX for games in the browser, if you pre-buffer them there is no loading delay at all, even if the file was cached before)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue here. Share the audio file or make the example reproducible.

Comment: I am 100% sure there is no dead space. How could the buffer help? 
I have just been trying using howler.js but it still doesn´t seem to work. It may be possible I am not using the library properly, I have just discovered it.